# Best practice: $rootScope or child $scope in unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I use a basic pattern in my unit tests (running with karma/jasmine) for my angular components and I do not manage to establish if my solution is safer or overkill than the one suggested by my coworkers:

**TL;DR: What are the pros/cons of working with $rootScope directly in unit tests (only!)?**

Here's my current pattern:

```
describe('component', function() {
  var $scope;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    //working with it now
    $scope.foo = 'fooValue';
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $scope.$destroy();
  });

  describe('subcomponent', function() {
    it('should do something', function() {
      //arrange
      //act
      //assert
    });
  });
});
```

And my coworkers suggest that using:

```
$scope = $rootScope;
```

**instead of**

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

would be simpler with no side-effect since `inject` creates a new `$injector` before each spec which provides  a new and clean`$rootScope`.

So, what could be the benefits / risks of these two solutions?

*Nota bene:* In our apps, we always avoid using `$rootScope` directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testing directly on the `$rootScope` should work just fine in most cases. However, if the component that you are testing injects `$rootScope` then the following weirdness happens:

- If you're testing a directive, then: `element.scope() === $rootScope`
- If you're testing a controller, then: `$scope === $rootScope`

(The above is true assuming you don't mock `$rootScope`). **Always instantiating a child scope via `$rootScope.$new()` as you've been doing is a safety measure which costs little to implement.**

Also keep in mind that `$rootScope` and `$rootScope.$new()` are not instances of the same *class*, although in practice this hardly seems to be an issue in unit testing...

### The **`$rootScope`** object:

[image: $rootScope]

### The child scope object created by **`$rootScope.$new()`**:

[image: $rootScope.$new()]

### The child isolated scope object created by **`$rootScope.$new(true)`**:

[image: $rootScope.$new(true)]

Comment: Thank you for this well detailed answer. There's a point I'm not sure about: when testing a directive `element.scope()` is not necessarily `$rootScope` because of the `$scompile(element)(scope)` step. Then I think `scope  === $rootScope` and `element.scope()` depends on the scope attribute set by the directive, right?

Comment: To support your answer: Do you know some 'reference' angular projects which have favored one solution more than the other?

Comment: @glepretre, Another way of stating it is if you compile the directive like this: `elm='<div directive></div>'; $compile(elm)($rootScope)`, then inside of the directive's link function, `$rootScope === element.scope()` will always be true.

Comment: even if in the directive attributes you create a child or isolate scope?

Comment: @glepretre, yes. If you don't create a child or isolate scope then in your directive link function: `$rootScope === element.scope() === scope` is true. Note that any time a directive doesn't create a new scope `element.scope() === scope` is always true.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there isn't much in it. The only practical difference between the `$rootScope` and child `$scope`s that I know of, is that `$parent` is `null` on `$rootScope`. Using `$parent` can be quite brittle, and so I wouldn't recommend it.

So as a first port of call, I would use

```
$scope = $rootScope;
```

If your component depends on `$parent` being not null, the test should fail, and you can decide whether to change the test to use

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

or change the component to not depend on `$parent`.

Comment: Good point. I also generally avoid the use of `$parent` for the reasons you pointed out.

Comment: Another reason to use `$scope = $rootScope.$new()` is if you are broadcasting or emitting events up/down the scope parent/child relationships

Comment: To support your answer: Do you know some 'reference' angular projects which have favored one solution more than the other?